# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable, i have tried the same formula with other simple function but it's not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

when i run this python 3 part of codes :

```
def tambah_edges(self,edges) :
    for z in (0,1) :
        for j in self.all_edges :
            if j[0][0] == j[1][0] and j[0][0]<j[1][1] :
                sisi = np.arange(j[0][1],j[1][1]+1)
                    for k in sisi :
                    v =  edges[z]==[j[0][0],k]
                        if v.all() :
                            #memisahkan edges yang berpotongan dengan edges baru
                            temp_1 = [j[0],edges[z]]
                            temp_2 = [edges[z],j[1]]
                            #menghapus edges dan nodes lama yang sudah terpotong
                            self.all_edges = np.delete(self.all_edges, np.where(self.all_edges == j))
                            #memasukkan edges baru
                            self.all_edges = np.concatenate(temp_1,axis=0)
                            self.all_edges = np.concatenate(temp_2,axis=0)
                            #memasukkan nodes baru
                            if not edges[z] in self.all_nodes :
                                self.all_nodes = np.append(self.all_nodes,edges[z],axis=0)
                                self.intersection = np.append(self.intersection,edges[z],axis=0)
```

and suddenly i get error messages saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isama\Desktop\eksperimen\cpp.py", line 499, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Isama\Desktop\eksperimen\cpp.py", line 482, in main
    map_exploration()
  File "C:\Users\Isama\Desktop\eksperimen\cpp.py", line 468, in map_exploration
    robot.tambah_edges(ez)
  File "C:\Users\Isama\Desktop\eksperimen\cpp.py", line 169, in tambah_edges
    if j[0][0] == j[1][0] and j[0][0]<j[1][1] :
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

i don't understand why this is such a problem, i have tried this codes with another more simple one and it's working

the self.all_edges is an 3d array which contain this :

```
[[[ 5  1]
  [ 5  6]]

 [[ 5  6]
  [12  6]]

 [[12  6]
  [12  1]]

 [[12  1]
  [14  1]]

 [[14  1]
  [14 14]]

 [[14 14]
  [ 1 14]]

 [[ 1 14]
  [ 1  1]]

 [[ 1  1]
  [ 5  1]]]
```

the other time i use the same format with this code  with more simple task :

```
def kuda(self) :
        for j in self.all_edges :
            if j[0][0] == j[1][0] and j[0][1] < j[1][1]:
                print(j)
```

and it prints this :

```
[[5 1]
 [5 6]]
[[14  1]
 [14 14]]
```

from the error message of first example, i'm kinda sure the problem with the 'j' array indexing, but i don't understand why it's working on one set of problem and not the other one

i'm new to python, i'll much appreciate any help from you all

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide also a sample input

Comment: what is `type(self.all_edges)` ?

Comment: it's <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: i've edited the post to give an alternative sample form

Comment: Consider running a debugger over the part that breaks. Also, index numpy arrays as `a[i, j]`, not `a[i][j]`. There are subtle differences.